# Modo landscape não funciona

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu já fiz o layout para o modo portrait e criei a pasta layout-land e colei todos os arquivos xml que já tenho para poder ir ajustando. 
Pelo que eu li, é só fazer isso mas não está funcionando, retirei vários componentes de uma das telas para testar e ela continua a mesma nos dois modos.

**xml do landscape:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        style="@style/estiloTela"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAAAAAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se a estrutura do seu diretório de recursos ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso negativo siga os seguintes passos:

1) Sobre o diretório de layout clique em : New -> Layout resource file

2) Na caixa de diálogo em File Name coloque o mesmo nome do layout xml de origem

3) Na lista de Available qualifiers selecione Orientation e adicione na lista da direita.

4) Selecione a orientação e clique em OK.

5) Copie seu layout original para o novo e modifique.

Comment: Tem 2 arquivos xmls para cada tela, mas não apareceu "port" do lado do xml portrait, apareceu só o land. Tem algum problema?

Comment: Não, não tem problema, a impressão que dá é que você digitou alguma coisa errada. Tente criar um outro layout qualquer com as duas orientações, teste e veja a estrutura.

Comment: Verifique se no seu AndroidManifest.xml  tem na tag application ou na tag activity -> android:screenOrientation="orientação"

Comment: Não tem nada no manifest. Criei uma tela de teste do jeito que você falou e deu certo. Será q vou ter q fazer esse processo para todas as telas? Tem umas 30 :(

Comment: Penso que não! No androidStudio aba "Project" (lateral esquerda aba vertical) sete a visualização de "Android" para "Project" (abas horizontais) e dê uma olhada na estrutura de diretórios do resource. Veja se o teste de layout não ficou numa estrutura diferente.

Comment: Deu certinho! muito obrigada :)